# C# WCF using messages from client

Tags: c#, wcf

am trying to create WCF client to consume the service, which contains messages.
So far I am trying to communicate with by messages, that are made of an header (DateTime) and the body which is an object called User.
I have imported the app.config and the Proxy by using svcutil.
But, I get few errors.
Code:

```
    {
        RegistryServiceClient client = new RegistryServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IRegistryService");
        UserMessage message = new UserMessage();


        message.time = DateTime.Now;

        message.user.id = "1";
        message.user.firstname = "John";
        message.user.lastname = "Smith";

        client.RegisterUser(message.time, message);
    }
```

Errors:
Error   2   Argument 1 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
Error   3   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UserMessage' to 'ref www.domain.co.uk.User.user'
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'RegistryServiceClient.RegisterUser(ref System.DateTime, ref www.domain.co.uk.User.user)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I have tried to mess about with ref by checking on the microsoft page but it did not lead me anyway really

Comment: Can you post the signature for the RegisterUser method on your service?

Comment: it is users.Adduser(message);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *RegisterUser* method signature specifies a different type than your *UserMessage*, specifically a type called *www.domain.co.uk.User.user*. I don't know the specifics of the *UserMessage* class, but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the *user* property is of type *www.domain.co.uk.User.user*. So try:

```
client.RegisterUser(ref message.time, ref message.user)
```

and see what happens.